# Data structure adding and removing items using constructor functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, push

Its the beginning of a data structure exercise and I am trying to write an add and remove function -its should be so simple and I don't get why its wrong?! Also the way to do it 8using a constructor function, prototype etc. must stay the way it is)
Any help much appreciated!

```
function Thestack () {
  this.array=[];
}

 Thestack.prototype.plus = function (i) {
   this.array.push(i);
  return this; // cannot be edited
 };

Thestack.prototype.minus = function () {
 this.array.pop();
};

var smallstack = new Thetack();

smallstack.plus(something); //followed by
smallstack.minus();

 should return: something
```

Comment: _"should return: something"_ ? Don't you want `.remove` to work ?

Comment: You are calling `stack.add()` and `stack.remove()`, but you defined methods called `.plus()` and `.minus()`, not a method called `.remove()` or `.add()`.  Why?  You also have a constructor named `Thestack`, but your code does `new Thetack()` (different spelling).  Please organize a question without typos in it.

Comment: var smallstack = new "Thetack();" typo??

Answer (score 1):

your minus function does not have a return statement, so it just returns undefined by default

You could as in the `add` function return `this` so you can continue chaining of methods, return the element removed or return the length of the remaing array

```
// return this for chaining
Thestack.prototype.minus = function () {
 this.data.pop();
 return this;
};

// return the removed item
Thestack.prototype.minus = function () {
  //edits the data array in place and returns the last element
  return this.data.pop();
};

// return the length of the remaining array
Thestack.prototype.minus = function () {
  this.data.pop();
  return this.data.length;
};
```

Comment: Uhh, they don't have a `.remove()` method defined at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, was referring to minus method. thank you

Comment: thank you, now it all works! totally forgot to return!